# Store images that were not uploaded

Tags: playframework

I have followed the tutorials for storing an image using the Play framework which works great but am now curious on how you can leverage the models to store an image that was not uploaded. In my case, when the user uploads a file, I do some processing and generate an image. I would then like to write this image to the DB. If the image field in the model is of data type Blob, what is the correct way to create the Blob from the image file generated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Image.data is a Blob field:

```
InputStream is = ...
String typeOfAttachment = ...

image.data.set(is,typeOfAttachment)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will give this a try but makes sense.